# I have these 2 tonnage calculators. The first one is working great. How can I fix the second one? Is something wrong with my Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would also like if I could have the value printed on the screen instead of showing up as an alert. For some reason my code was working when I only had the 1 calculator on the screen but when I tried adding a second one and modifying the javascript a little bit so the second one works as well both stopped working.

THANKS!

```js
sum = {
  "al": 12,
  "mm": 20,
  "hm": 30,
  
}
let val;
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page loads  
  document.getElementById("tensile").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var tgt = e.target; // what was clicked
    if (tgt.name == "size") { // is it one of the radios?
      val = tgt.value; // save the value once (DRY principle) 
    }
  })

  $('.ck').click(function() {
    var a = parseFloat($('.n1').val());
    var b = parseFloat($('.n2').val());
    var z = 3.14;
    var c = a * b * z * sum[val];
    alert(c);
  })
})

sum = {
  "al1": 12,
  "mm1": 20,
  "hm1": 30,
  
}
let val1;
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page loads  
  document.getElementById("tensile1").addEventListener("click", function(g) {
    var tgt1 = g.target; // what was clicked
    if (tgt1.name == "size") { // is it one of the radios?
      val1 = tgt1.value; // save the value once (DRY principle) 
    }
  })

  $('.ck1').click(function() {
    var a1 = parseFloat($('.n3').val());
    var b1 = parseFloat($('.n4').val());
    var c1 = parseFloat($('.m2').val());
    var z1 = 3.14;
    var d1 = a1 * b1 * z1 * sum[val1];
    alert(d1);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <h1>ROUND HOLE</h1>

  Diameter<input type="text" class="n1" /><br /> Metal Thickness<input type="text" class="n2" /><br />

  <h3> Select Metal </h3>
  <form id="tensile">
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="al">Alum
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="mm">Mild Metal<br>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="hm"> Heavy Metal<br>
    <br>
  </form>
  <hr />

  <input type="button" value="Add" class="ck" />
</div>

<div>
  <h1>RECTANGLE HOLE</h1>

  Length<input type="text" class="n3" /><br /> 
  width<input type="text" class="n4" /><br />
  Metal Thickness<input type="text" class="m2" /><br />

  <h3> Select Metal </h3>
  <form id="tensile1">
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="al1">Alum
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="mm1">Mild Metal<br>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="hm1"> Heavy Metal<br>
    <br>
  </form>
  <hr />

  <input type="button" value="Add" class="ck1" />
</div>
```

Comment: your jQuery librairie is declared twice, your jQuery librairie is declared twice

Comment: Can you point me to where that is, please? I am very new to jQuery and JS in general

Comment: as @MisterJojo pointed out. Search for this in your file and remove duplicate `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library, you should use only one declaration.

Comment: Hi there I removed the duplicate @deep206. I am getting a NAN value for the first calculator now and the add button produces nothing for the second calculator

Comment: How do I declare the sum elements please? Sum was working before for the first calculator when it was on its own its own HTML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the corect way to code that (IMHO) :

```js
const 
  myForm  = document.forms['my-form']
, sDigits = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { maximumFractionDigits: 4, minimumFractionDigits: 2 })
, Metal   = { al: 12, mm: 20, hm: 30 } 
  ; 
myForm['bt-control-round'].onclick = () =>
  {
  let val = myForm['diameter-round'].valueAsNumber
          * myForm['thickness-round'].valueAsNumber
          * 3.14
          * Metal[ myForm['metal-round'].value ] 
          ;
  // alert( `round hole:\n ${val.toFixed(4)}` )
  myForm['out-control-round'].value = isNaN(val) ? 'bad entrie(s)' : sDigits.format(val) 
  }
myForm['bt-control-rect'].onclick = () =>
  {
  let val = myForm['length-rect'].valueAsNumber
          * myForm['width-rect'].valueAsNumber
          * myForm['thickness-rect'].valueAsNumber
    //      * 3.14
          * Metal[ myForm['metal-rect'].value ] 
          ;
  // alert( `rectangle hole:\n ${val.toFixed(4)}` )
  myForm['out-control-rect'].value = isNaN(val) ? 'bad entrie(s)' : sDigits.format(val)  
  }
myForm.onsubmit = evt => { evt.preventDefault() } // disable submit
```

```css
form {
  font-family    : 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size      : 14px;
  }
form legend {
  text-transform : capitalize;
  padding        : 0 1em;
  }
form fieldset { 
  margin-top     : 1em;
  width          : 20em; 
  }
form .backLine,
form .backLinePlus,
form .backLinePlus * { 
  display        : block;
  float          : left;
  clear          : both;
  }
form label.cVal { 
  margin-top     : .7em;
  }
form label.cVal  span { 
  font-size      : .9em;
  padding-right  : .2em;
  font-weight    : bold;
  }
form h5 {
  margin         : 1em 0 .2em 0;
  } 
form label.cCheck input {
  vertical-align : text-bottom;
  }
form output {
  font-size      : 1.4em;
  font-weight    : bold;
  text-align     : center;
  background     : lightblue;
  padding        : .3em;
  box-sizing     : border-box;
  width          : 100%;
  margin         : .3em 0;
  }
```

```html
<form name="my-form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>round hole</legend>
    <label class="backLinePlus cVal">
      <span>Diameter :</span> 
      <input name="diameter-round" type="number" value="0" min="0" step="any" >
    </label>
    <label class="backLinePlus cVal">
      <span>Metal Thickness :</span> 
      <input name="thickness-round" type="number" value="0" min="0" step="any" >
    </label>
    <h5 class="backLine">Select Metal</h5>
    <label class=" cCheck backLine">
      <input name="metal-round" value="al" type="radio" checked >
      <span>Alum</span> 
    </label>
    <label class="cCheck backLine">
      <input name="metal-round" value="mm" type="radio"  >
      <span>Mild Metal</span> 
    </label>
    <label class="cCheck backLine">
      <input name="metal-round" value="hm" type="radio"  >
      <span>Heavy Metal</span> 
    </label>
    <h5 class="backLine"> </h5>
    <button type="button" name="bt-control-round" class="backLine">⚙ calc</button>
    <output name="out-control-round" class="backLine">...</output>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>rectangle hole</legend>
    <label class="backLinePlus cVal">
      <span>length :</span> 
      <input name="length-rect" type="number" value="0" min="0" step="any">
    </label>
    <label class="backLinePlus cVal">
      <span>width :</span> 
      <input name="width-rect" type="number" value="0" min="0" step="any" >
    </label>
    <label class="backLinePlus cVal">
      <span>Metal Thickness :</span> 
      <input name="thickness-rect" type="number" value="0" min="0" step="any" >
    </label>
    <h5 class="backLine">Select Metal</h5>
    <label class=" cCheck backLine">
      <input name="metal-rect" value="al" type="radio" checked >
      <span>Alum</span> 
    </label>
    <label class="cCheck backLine">
      <input name="metal-rect" value="mm" type="radio"  >
      <span>Mild Metal</span> 
    </label>
    <label class="cCheck backLine">
      <input name="metal-rect" value="hm" type="radio"  >
      <span>Heavy Metal</span> 
    </label>
    <h5 class="backLine"> </h5>
    <button type="button" name="bt-control-rect" class="backLine">❏ calc</button>
    <output name="out-control-rect" class="backLine">...</output>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you JoJo I like this one! I like being able to put decimals though because its going to have fine precision for what the user can enter. But I do like it a lot regardless!

Comment: @Skorpios I added alert info precision on 4 decimal, but you can change it

Comment: @Skorpios you can put decimal in the inputs, You can also change step value to `step="0.05"` or what ever you want

Comment: Are we able to return the value in a text box rather than an alert? I think that would be more intuitive? Also thank you so much for the code!

Comment: Awesome I see that now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your `sum` object is declared twice. The second declaration overwrites the first, so the keys needed for the first calculator are lost.

Comment: How am I able to fix this please?

Comment: If the key values are the same in both cases, simply remove the second declaration. In this case, you also need to remove the "1" characters in the "value" attributes in the second group of radio buttons.

Comment: The key values are different. I got the first calculator working fine now. The second one is saying NaN. Any suggestions?

Comment: Then rename that object to "sum1" and refer to it in the second calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The first one throw an error because you reassigned `sum`. For instance the first one looks for the value of `al` key but there isn't anymore because you reassigned it, there is `al1`. So you should assign `sum` once and it should be as following:

```
let sum = {
  "al": 12,
  "mm": 20,
  "hm": 30,
  "al1": 12,
  "mm1": 20,
  "hm1": 30,
}
```

**Here is the working example:**

```js
let sum = {
  "al": 12,
  "mm": 20,
  "hm": 30,
  "al1": 12,
  "mm1": 20,
  "hm1": 30
}
let val;
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page loads  
  document.getElementById("tensile").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var tgt = e.target; // what was clicked
    if (tgt.name == "size") { // is it one of the radios?
      val = tgt.value; // save the value once (DRY principle) 
    }
  })

  $('.ck').click(function() {
    var a = parseFloat($('.n1').val());
    var b = parseFloat($('.n2').val());
    var z = 3.14;
    var c = a * b * z * sum[val];
    alert(c);
  })
})


let val1;
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page loads  
  document.getElementById("tensile1").addEventListener("click", function(g) {
    var tgt1 = g.target; // what was clicked
    if (tgt1.name == "size") { // is it one of the radios?
      val1 = tgt1.value; // save the value once (DRY principle) 
    }
  })

  $('.ck1').click(function() {
    var a1 = parseFloat($('.n3').val());
    var b1 = parseFloat($('.n4').val());
    var c1 = parseFloat($('.m2').val());
    var z1 = 3.14;
    var d1 = a1 * b1 * c1 * z1 * sum[val1];
    alert(d1);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <h1>ROUND HOLE</h1>

  Diameter<input type="text" class="n1" /><br /> Metal Thickness<input type="text" class="n2" /><br />

  <h3> Select Metal </h3>
  <form id="tensile">
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="al">Alum
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="mm">Mild Metal<br>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="hm"> Heavy Metal<br>
    <br>
  </form>
  <hr />

  <input type="button" value="Add" class="ck" />
</div>

<div>
  <h1>RECTANGLE HOLE</h1>

  Length<input type="text" class="n3" /><br /> 
  width<input type="text" class="n4" /><br />
  Metal Thickness<input type="text" class="m2" /><br />

  <h3> Select Metal </h3>
  <form id="tensile1">
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="al1">Alum
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="mm1">Mild Metal<br>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="hm1"> Heavy Metal<br>
    <br>
  </form>
  <hr />

  <input type="button" value="Add" class="ck1" />
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that and still getting NaN for the second calculator for some reason

Comment: NICE! Now both calculators are working but for some reason, the second one is giving me the same value as the first one?

Comment: Maybe one of the variables has an issue?

Comment: Please double check, it works fine for me.

Comment: Will do thank you! But like even if you try to run the code snipet here. I tried inputting 5 for each field. It gives me the same answer for both calculators.

Comment: try now! you've forgotten adding `c1` in this part `var d1 = a1 * b1 * c1 * z1 * sum[val1];`. That's why it was calculating the same.